# Grep console -saving filter console tabs

Tags: intellij-idea, plugins

Every single time I run debug, I lose my filter tabs.
How do I keep them, so I don't have to add it manually each time.
That's what I thought "expression groups" were for in the settings?

[image]

Comment: If the Pin button does not work, the it is a bug.

Comment: yah just tried this pin..no luck.

Comment: looked at the code- can't figure it out..still a noobie to programming

Comment: Pin button works on my machine with IDEA 2017.3